# JAR file with picture

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I made a small java program with a `Frame` showing a small `ImageIcon`. I'm using IntelliJ to make my programs. When I click on "Run", it shows me the `Frame` with the picture. Then I made a JAR file out of it, and now it just shows me the `Frame` but not the `Image`. What can I do?

Comment: Did you added the image to the project Resources folder?

Comment: You don't need to "sign" your posts with your username, we can see who posts the question. Anyways, please show some code in an [edit] to your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: For examples, see [tag:embedded-resource] under _learn more…_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the picture to your resources folder, and insert it in your classpath!

Comment: Do you mean with "You must add the picture to your resources folder" that i have to create a resource folder and add that picture into there? If so, I did that already. And how can I insert it into my classpath?

Comment: Could you add more details to this answer? Thanks

Comment: Which detail do you need?

Comment: It depends on the IDE you´re using! check IDE doc. Then you´ll probably have to use: getClass().getResource("/someImage.png");